# Linux/Fedora Issue with NginX-Docker and maybe IPV6

Tags: fedora, docker, nginx, ipv6

I'm attempting to setup Nginx-Docker on Fedora 38 Plasma KDE (nearly fresh install).  Nginx works fine connecting to my react-server (non-docker) running locally on port 3000.  However, Nginx fails to connect to my backend-server (scala, http4s, non-docker) running locally.  I also have 2 postgres instances running in docker on port 5433 & 5432, which the backend connects to.

```
docker exec -it nginx-proxy curl host.docker.internal:4001/graphiql.html
curl: (7) Failed to connect to host.docker.internal port 4001 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server

curl localhost:4001/graphiql.html
# successful response

docker exec -it nginx-proxy curl host.docker.internal:3000
# successful response

curl localhost:3000
# successful response
```

When using netstat, I noticed the backend server is using tcp6 & react-server is not. (Postgres on both tcp and tcp6).  The `tcp6` stood out because I also experienced issues with git & npm, which were resolved by forcing them to use `ipv4`.

I don't know that my current issue is `tcp6` related, so this could be a red-herring.  If it is tcp6 related, it seems logical it's not hardware, because everything is running on my laptop.

```
$ netstat -anp | grep -E ':3000|:4001|:5433|:5432'
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      61886/node-18       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5433            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:4001          :::*                    LISTEN      59873/java          
tcp6       0      0 :::5433                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

I could perhaps try to figure out how to force my backend server to run over IPV4, or even dockerize it, but if that works, that may only delay the next dozen random unexpected IPV6 issues.

Nginx docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

nginx.conf

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location /graphql {
            proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:4001/graphql;
        }
        location /graphiql.html {
            proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:4001/graphiql.html;
        }
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:3000;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

    }
}
```